# How can I read performance counters from the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, intel-pmu

I have been using the Linux perf tool in the user space. I want to write code that reads performance counters for a thread every time it does a context switch.

The steps required are:

1) Get a mechanism to read the performance counter registers.

2) Call step(1) from the scheduler after every context switch.

I am stuck at step(1) as I could not figure out which functions to call for reading the performance registers and how to describe an event while doing it. 
I tried going through the docs and also this question [How do I use performance counters inside of the kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765275/how-do-i-use-performance-counters-inside-of-the-kernel).

Comment: `perf` is a tool for using the performance counters subsystem in Linux. How are you using `perf` ? Which performance counters are you looking to read from ? Do you have an example where you have tried to use `perf` from userspace ?

Comment: Yes, I have been using perf for some time. The counters I wish to measure are all there in perf list events, basically all the Hardware cache events. I have only used it from the user space till now with the -I flag which gave me counters after a fixed intervel.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this entirely with `perf` by using *tracepoint events* and *group leader sampling*.

The `sched:sched_switch` is a tracepoint event triggering on every context switch. Putting that event with other events into a group with enabled group leader sampling will allow you to read the non-leader counters whenever a leader sample happens. The syntax looks like this:

```
perf record -e "{sched:sched_switch,cycles,instructions}:S" -a
```

This will record `cycles` values and `instructions` on every CPU whenever there is a context switch. You can check the output with `perf script`, which also allows you to read it with python programs.

If you want to monitor in your own program, you can use `perf_event_open` with `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP` and `PERF_SAMPLE_READ`.

The `perf` tools and it's underlying `perf_event_open` interface are very powerful, but the documentation can sometimes be lacking. If you need even more flexibility, you can use [BPF](https://www.iovisor.org/technology/ebpf) and [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc).

Comment: I think we can use a similar command for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674710/using-pebs-and-linux-perf-to-count-the-number-of-cpu-cycles-passed-to-execute-x.

Comment: Thanks @Zulan, How can I access the counter values in run time? I am planning to this in the kernel itself, but not quite sure, how to. Also, can you comment on the overhead involved?

Comment: *Why* do you want to implement stuff in the kernel when the kernel is capable of doing this for you already? It even allows you to run your own code using BPF. Modifying the kernel code itself is so much more complicated and rather fragile.

Comment: The overhead depends... on context switch rate, number and type of counters to read, .... You will have to **measure** to figure out the overhead in your particular case.